# CV2 counting pixels wrong

Tags: python, opencv

I have imported a bunch of tif-files using cv2 but it seems like cv2 reads the number of pixels wrong. The original tif looks like this:

[image: Image before import with cv2]

But when I do a simple import:

```
n = cv2.imread(img)
```

And I want to check the array, the array has decided that there are 11 pixels and that the top row and the far right column is just black pixels. Looking at the shape also tells me it counts 11 pixels on a 10-pixel image. The array looks like:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   4   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   3   3   3   1   3   1   0   0   0   0
6   3   3   3   1   0   2   0   2   0   0
4   6   8   5   4   2   3   3   3   2   0
3   6   7   6   3   1   2   4   4   2   0
4   6   7   7   5   3   2   4   4   3   0
3   4   5   5   5   5   1   0   9   7   0
3   2   2   2   2   5   7   3   5   9   0
2   3   4   1   2   6   8   7   9   4   0
1   3   5   4   2   4   4   6   7   9   0
```

And the print of the imported image looks like:
[image: Matplotlib representation]

But why!? Why are there an added border and can you help me convince cv2 to stop being a jerk?

Edit: Tif added here:

[Original tif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4NIt.png)

Comment: please upload also the original image

Comment: This was just examples - to show how all images looks like before and after. I have more than one million tif-files in that folder and I just picked two for clarification.

Comment: No, windows 10 running py3.7

Comment: Please show the code you use to print the file pixel values. Is the input grayscale and being color mapped or a color image? Best not to confuse people using pyplot to show images. You should save results using cv2.imwrite() to post results. Can you post your original tif without the zoom effect, so others can test with it?

Comment: The image is RGB. When I go with:

    cv2.imwrite("C:\\image.tif", cv_img[80])

It still creates the black edge as before. The original tif is that low res. They are all 10x10 pix. Tif added to post.

Comment: Oooohhhh shit. I just saw that a white border was added when I uploaded it here..... how weird! Doesn't show up when I just open the tif.

Comment: You've also posted a PNG file, not the TIFF you refer to everywhere. Please post actual images, not screen-grabs or poorly cropped zooms, or different formats... use Dropbox or Google Drive if Stack Overflow won't accept your images. Thank you.